# I'm trying to display the value of each checkbox selected into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox

I've looked around on the site but I can't seem to get any of the solutions working for me

I'm trying to display the value of each checkbox selected into a div in an array format

```
<section id="inputs">
    
    <div class="row">
    
      <div class="col nopad text-center">
       <label class="image-checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" id="user" name="image[]" value="Yoga"/>
       <img src="image.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
       <p>Yoga</p>
       </label>
     </div>
    
     <div class="col nopad text-center">
       <label class="image-checkbox"  id="image-checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" name="image[]" value="Gymnastics" />
       <img src="image.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
       <p>Gymnastics</p> 
      </label>
     </div>
    
     <div class="col nopad text-center">
       <label class="image-checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" name="image[]" value="Aerial Acrobatics" />
       <img src="image.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
       <p>Aerial Acrobatics</p> 
      </label>
     </div>
<div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please show what you tried. It should be a simple `forEach` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create an array let's say `selectedBoxes`.
- Select all the `checkboxes` using `querySelectorAll`.
- Loop through all the `checkboxes` and add a `change` listener to all of them.
- Finally, inside the change handler, just check if the checkbox being changed is currently in the array, if it is simply remove it from the array, otherwise add to the array.

(*For brevity I've removed the images and the p tag inside the labels*)

```js
const selectedBoxes = [];
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

checkboxes.forEach((box, i) => {
  box.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const idx = selectedBoxes.findIndex(v => v === e.target.value);

    if (idx === -1) selectedBoxes.push(e.target.value);
    else selectedBoxes.splice(idx, 1);

    console.clear();
    console.log(selectedBoxes);
  })
});
```

```html
<section id="inputs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col nopad text-center">
      <label class="image-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="user" name="image[]" value="Yoga" />
        Yoga
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col nopad text-center">
      <label class="image-checkbox" id="image-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="image[]" value="Gymnastics" />
        Gymnastics
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col nopad text-center">
      <label class="image-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="image[]" value="Aerial Acrobatics" />
        Aerial Acrobatics
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<ul id="selected-boxes">
</ul>
```

Comment: @ryan. Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to display the value of each checkbox selected into a div in an array format

```
const container = document.getElementById("inputs");
const checkBoxes = Array.from(container.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')).filter(el => el.type === "checkbox");
// Go wild here
const allChecked = checkBoxes.filter(e => e.checked);
const allUnchecked = checkBoxes.filter(e => !e.checked);
const stringOfCheck = checkBoxes.map(e => e.checked ? "checked" : "unchecked").join(',');
```

`Array.from` turns the nodeList into an proper array, you can then use that array of elements to get their values and properties

Answer (score 0):

```js
const chbox = document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]');
const res = document.querySelector('#res');


chbox.forEach(ch=>{
  ch.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  if(ch.checked){
      res.innerText += ch.value + '\n'
  }else{
      res.innerText = res.innerText.replace(ch.value+'\n','')
  }
  })
})
```

```html
<section id="inputs">
    
    <div class="row">
    
      <div class="col nopad text-center">
       <label class="image-checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" id="user" name="image[]" value="Yoga"/>
       <img src="image.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
       <p>Yoga</p>
       </label>
     </div>
    
     <div class="col nopad text-center">
       <label class="image-checkbox"  id="image-checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox"  name="image[]" value="Gymnastics" />
       <img src="image.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
       <p>Gymnastics</p> 
      </label>
     </div>
    
     <div class="col nopad text-center">
       <label class="image-checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" name="image[]" value="Aerial Acrobatics" />
       <img src="image.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
       <p>Aerial Acrobatics</p> 
      </label>
     </div>
     
     <h4>Checked values : </h4> 
     <div id="res">
     </div>
<div>
</section>
```